# Error if RewriteEngine On - says FollowSymLinks is off

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched everywhere (including here) but can't find the right answer to this one!

I've taken over control of a newly set up web server and all may not be ideally set (yet) but I'm unable to use RewriteEngine On in a .htaccess file.  The error log says that it can't be done because FollowSymLinks is off.

Except that I can't see WHERE it is off!

this is CentOS release 6.5 (Final) with Apache 5.4.30

web files are stored in /home/domain-name/public_html and 
httpd.conf has (amongst other things)

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +Includes -Indexes +MultiViews
    XBitHack On
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.htm index.shtml index.php default.html default.htm default.shtml
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName server52218.uk2net.com
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Includes IncludesNOEXEC Indexes MultiViews
            XBitHack On
            AllowOverride All
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.htm index.shtml index.php default.html default.htm default.shtml
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/sites">
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Includes -Indexes MultiViews
    XBitHack On
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.htm index.shtml index.php default.html default.htm default.shtml
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The individual site config files do nothing spectacular; specify DocumentRoot, ScriptAlias, ServerName/Alias and Logs.

If a website has a need to use rewrite, the .htaccess file has RewriteEngine On and this causes the error to occur and be shown in the error log.  Remove that line and the web site displays OK (except, of course, that the rewrites don't now work!)

This is exactly the same setup (as far as I can see) that they had on the old server but that was running CentOS 5.10 with Apache 2.2.3

I've tried specifying the Options directive in the htaccess file but still no joy.

What am I missing?  Where do I look next??

Typically /home/domain-name/public_html/.htaccess contains

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: What's your htaccess file look like?

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess file?

Comment: I've added a typical htaccess file to the question above (don't seem able to do formatting in this comment).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this was all down to a statement in /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf which said

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Changing the Options statement to

```
Options -Indexes
```

Seems to have made things work again.  I'm not really sure why, though.